# How to deal with org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException during application launch?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I am learning hibernate/spring mvc and i have an exception by starting the server. I am working in intellij and this database is connected to my IDE and working perfect (also "test connection" is ok), but when i am trying to create a bean in config file, it's not working at all. 
What could be a problem?

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.packt.webstore")
public class RootApplicationContextConfig {
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("root");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop");
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new 
    LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    props.put("hibernate.dialect",
        "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.packt.webstore");
    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionalManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new
            HibernateTransactionManager();

    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory()
        .getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }
}
```

Exception log:

```
Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied 
dependency expressed through field 'productService': Error creating 
bean with name 'productServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed 
through field 'products': Error creating bean with name 
'productDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 
'factory': Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in 
com.packt.webstore.config.RootApplicationContextConfig: Invocation of 
init method failed; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC 
Connection for DDL execution;
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace from the logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

tells you that no `Connection` could be established to the configured database in the moment the code is executed. This could be caused by many reasons, thus I merely list the most likely ones:

1. MySQL is not running at all.

   - Did you start it? Verify by inspecting running process lists (depends on OS).
2. MySQL is not listening on Port 3306 which is the *default* port.

   - Did you change it? If so, change your code/config accordingly.
3. Given MySQL is running and listening (port 3306), the password for the *user* root is not `root`.

   - Did you set the password to `root`? Connect via mysql CLI locally with these credentials. If this works, you can rule out a password mismatch.
4. The user `root` lacks permissions to connect to the database with the name `shop` .

   - Did you change permissions for the user `root` restricting access to the `shop` database? If so, check and/or change permissions ([GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html)) for local connections by this user.

Hope this checklist helps.

#### Update-1

Depending on the driver version of the `mysql-connector.jar`, you have to carefully check/select a the name of the driver class:

- MySQL Connector/J 5.x

  - jdbc.driver_class => `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
- MySQL Connector/J 6.x+

  - jdbc.driver_class => `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: Thank you for the hints, i just wrote another java program only with jdbc connection to the database with the same settings, and it is working without any problems

Comment: If these hints helped you and you learned from it, consider granting an upvote to my answer.

Comment: no, unfortunately it is still not working in my program, but i am sure that all settings (password/login/ports etc) are correct

Answer (score 0):

Changed to Hibernate 5 and mysql 5.1.39

Comment: Such details were missing in the original post. :/

Comment: you are right, sry, i had mysql 6 and hibernate 4, i thought that it couldn't be a problem

Comment: Hint: Use the more recent version 5.1.46, see here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.46